# solidity hexadecimal error code

Tags: solidity, hex

i know hexadecimal charchter ( 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F)

when i write code

```
string a= hex"011a" //it is ok
```

but when write this code

```
string a=hex"011aa" // get Error
```

why? and how can i take advantage of this in solidity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add the characters in pairs, since a pair of hex digit is a byte.

The line that is showing an error has an uneven set of characters:

```js
string a=hex"011aa" // get Error
```

Better do this:

```js
string a2 =hex"011a0a";
```

Also, the reason is that you need to add bytes whose values are within the range (in decimal) of 0-127. Because those are the value printable UTF-8 characters that Solidity support.

For example, look at this table: https://www.asciitable.com/

You will see that it goes from 0 to 127 in decimal. In hexadecimal, the range goes from 0-7F.

If you try this:

```js
string a = hex"aa";
```

It will not work, because the decimal value of the hex `aa` is 170, and we know that it should not be greater than 127. So we are limited to the range 0-7F in hex:

```js
string min_max_accii_value = hex"00_7f";
```

Do your own conversion here: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html?x=aa

So, you can do something like this, and separate it with `_` to make it more readable:

```js
string a3 = hex"00_0a_7f";
```

Here the docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#unicode-literals

Answer (score 0):

Although its really unclear what you're trying to do, when you do
`string x = hex'something'`, the compiler will look for UTF-8 characters that corresponds to the hex number you entered, and is therefore is expecting an even number of characters (2 hex characters = 1 byte). As for your 2nd question, i don't really understand it, sorry, you can... Use that to output non printable characters, i guess? (which is what you're doing with the 1st string, 01 and 1a are both non printable characters in UTF-8) But yeah, why would you do that?